# how to optimize safari browser?

Tags: safari

how to optimize safari browser?To make it faster.

Comment: Why do you have such an aversion to putting any thought into your questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be helpfull:

http://webkit.org/blog/166/optimizing-page-loading-in-web-browser/

Comment: That just explains their algorithm; it doesn't actually give the OP what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

[SafariSpeed](http://www.macinstruct.com/node/195) is what you need

> SafariSpeed allows you to enable Safari's debug menu, customize Safari's look and feel, and speed it up a little.